# Jdbc update statement in spark

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, databricks

I am connected to a database using JDBC and I am trying to run an update query. First I am typing the query, then I am executing it (in the same way I do the SELECT which works perfectly fine).

```
caseoutputUpdateQuery = "(UPDATE dbo.CASEOUTPUT_TEST SET NOTIFIED = 'YES') alias_output "
spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=caseoutputUpdateQuery, properties=connectionProperties)
```

When I run this I have the following error:

`A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement must have an OUTPUT clause.`

I tried to fix this in different ways but there is always another error. For example, I tried to rewrite the query in the following way:

```
caseoutputUpdateQuery = "(UPDATE dbo.CASEOUTPUT_TEST SET NOTIFIED = 'YES' OUTPUT DELETED.*, INSERTED.* FROM dbo.CASEOUTPUT_TEST) alias_output "
```

but I encounter this error:
`A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.`

The other way I tried to rewrite it was:

```
caseoutputUpdateQuery = "(INSERT INTO dbo.UpdateOutput(OldCaseID,NotifiedOld) SELECT * FROM( UPDATE dbo.CASEOUTPUT_TEST SET NOTIFIED = 'YES' OUTPUT deleted.OldCaseID,DELETED.NotifiedOld ) AS tbl) alias_output "
```

but I've got this error:

`A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed inside another nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement.`

I've literally tried everything I found on the internet but without luck. Do you have any suggestion on how I can fix this and run my update statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Spark is not designed for that UPDATE statement use case. That's not the scenario where Spark can help to deal with RDBMS. I suggest to use a direct connection using a JDBC from the code you are writing (I mean calling that JDBC directly). If you are using Scala you can use as suggested [here](http://guyharrison.squarespace.com/blog/2014/4/30/best-practices-for-accessing-oracle-from-scala-using-jdbc.html) (for example, but there are other multiple ways) or from Python as explained [here](https://www.oracletutorial.com/python-oracle/updating-data/). Those samples reach Oracle engine, but please change the driver/connector if you are using MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres or any other RDMBS

Answer (score 1):

spark.read under the covers does a select * from the source jdbc table.  if you pass a query, spark translates it to

select your query
from ( their query select *)

Sql complains because you are trying to do an update on a view "select * from"

Comment: What is the work around then?

Comment: you can connect directly to the db and send your generated sql to the db, rather than using spark to generate the sql.